# Creating a table with two different foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have to create a table with relationships to two different tables. Consider the example below.

Lets say I have following three tables:

```
1) Person -> person_id, residence_type (V or T)
2) Village -> village_id, village_name
3) Town -> town_id, town_name
```

Now what I want to do is create a foreign key reference in person table for the person's village or town. I thought of two ways.

One is to create one column of residence_name and just input id from village or town table and then query it based on residence_type whether its V or T. But surely I cannot create it as a foreign key reference for two different tables at same time.

Another option is to create two columns - v_id and t_id in person table and fill one based on residence_type. Again I can query it accordingly but surely cannot create it as foreign key reference as it cannot be NULL but in this case one column will always be NULL.

Which of the two approaches is better or is there any better approach which will allow me to create a foreign key reference?

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server? Those are two different products and the answer is different for each one.

Comment: Its MySQL so primarily I need a suggestion for that. But also put in SQL server as I have experienced it is more strict and if I ever need to migrate I might have to keep it in mind.

Comment: One possible solution for sql server would be to create v_id and t_Id with a check constrain that will allow only one of them to be null. MySql does not enforce check constraints so it will not work there. This is just one example, there are probably other examples too.

Comment: Your example is obviously oversimplified - this way, you don't even need separate tables for towns and villages. Make sure the answer, when given, will actually solve your real issue.

Comment: @RogerWolf its true, in my actual scenario, I do need separate tables. The reason being (again an over simplified example) - lets say the towns are fixed and have to come from a table (like a dropdown selection) but villages can be added by any user (like a text entry) so its a mutable list.

So in case a user lives in a town she would select it and hence town id will be maintained but if user lives in a village she would type the name of a village and it would go to separate village table with id being linked to the user.

Comment: @Parry, in that case, adding `VillageName nvarchar(100) null` to your `Person` table will solve the problem. Oh yes, and you actually can make `Person.TownId` column nullable. And you can control their mutual integrity by either a table-level check constraint, or by performing data modifications via stored procedure(s) rather than directly. If that still doesn't fit the bill, you'll have to provide more business requirements from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the design is somewhat "iffy". My assumption is that for a person you'd want to know what his residence is, i.e. ultimately name of village or town?

If that is the case, I'd remove the Village and Town tables and replace that with a Residence look up table which contains both Villages and towns, and which has a column to a ResidenceType table. The ResidenceType table would look something like so (this is SQL Server syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ResidenceType
(
  ResidenceTypeID smallint NOT NULL,
  ResidenceTypeDefinition nvarchar(25),
  CONSTRAINT [pk_ResidenceType] PRIMARY KEY (ResidenceTypeID),
);
```

You would then populate that table like so:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ResidenceType(ResidenceTypeID, ResidenceTypeDefinition)
VALUES (1, 'Village'), (2, 'Town');
```

Now you can create a Residence table, whoch would hold both town and village names - and it would have a foreign key against the ResidenceType table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Residence
(
  ResidenceID int NOT NULL,
  ResidenceTypeID smallint NOT NULL,
  ResidenceName nvarchar(25),
  CONSTRAINT [pk_Residence] PRIMARY KEY (ResidenceID),
  CONSTRAINT [fk_ResidenceTypeID] FOREIGN KEY (ResidenceTypeID)
  REFERENCES dbo.ResidenceType(ResidenceTypeID),
);
```

Add some data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Residence(ResidenceID, ResidenceTypeID, ResidenceName)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Village 1'),
       (2, 1, 'Village 2'),
       (3, 2, 'Town 1'),
       etc...
```

Finally your Person table would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person
(
  PersonID bigint NOT NULL,
  ResidenceID int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [pk_Person] PRIMARY KEY (PersonID),
  CONSTRAINT [fk_Person_ResidenceID] FOREIGN KEY (ResidenceID)
  REFERENCES dbo.Residence(ResidenceID),
);
```

That's the way I would suggest you'd do it. You are now following best practices when it comes to normalization etc.

Comment: Thanks, this actually makes much sense to me and I guess I am inclined to use this. I have one doubt though. The reason I need separate tables is that one list is fixed and other is mutable - to explain it using over simplified example its as this ---  **Lets say that Town list is fixed and cannot be changed to user can only select from a specific town but Village list is mutable so user can add name of village in text box. So if user lives in town user selects from a drop down list which comes from a table for Town and for Village user enters the name (for which I created a Village table)**

Comment: Do you think your approach can work in this scenario too or is it better to have separate town and village tables.

Comment: Hi Parry, that is a front-end issue. I.e.the the front-end decides what can be done. So I would say the example I gave would work for your scenario above.

Comment: Thanks. I decided, I will use the scenario you gave. Makes my db simple and would require lesser queries compared with a two table scenario.

Comment: Cool! Glad to be of help!